# How to Add Multiple Rows in MySQL Php

Tags: php, mysql, sum

i want to plus amount + servicecharges  + replacecharges + blockcharges + othercharges

but it is not working please help me to fix this issue 
thanks

```
$sql="SELECT CONCAT(monthdate,' ','(',drivernamefuel,')') as drivernamefuel,sum(amount) +  'servicecharges' + 'replacecharges' + 'blockcharges' + 'othercharges' AS amount,drivernamefuel FROM $tablename where carno='$c' AND monthdate BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' GROUP BY monthdate";
```

See ScreenShort
File #1: http://www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1381252318.jpg

File #2: http://www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1381228480.jpg

it is showing these error
Warning: Division by zero in indexssds.php on line 51

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in indexssds.php on line 73

here is complete code please check my update
thanks ...........................

```
 <?php
include 'config.php';
$link=mysql_connect("$hostname","$username","$password")or 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link);
function formatMoney($number, $fractional=false) {
    if ($fractional) {
        $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number);
    }
    while (true) {
        $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
        if ($replaced != $number) {
            $number = $replaced;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $number;
}       
$a=$_POST['from'];
$b=$_POST['to'];
$c=$_POST['to2'];
echo " <p align='center' class='style1'>Vehicle No: $c </p>"; 
echo "<span  align='center' class='style1'>Report For The Period Of $a to $b </span>"; 

include 'create.php';
$sql="SELECT CONCAT(monthdate,' ','(',drivernamefuel,')') as drivernamefuel, 
SUM(ifnull(amount,0) +  
ifnull(servicecharges,0)  + 
ifnull(replacecharges,0)  + 
ifnull(blockcharges,0)  + 
ifnull(othercharges,0) ) AS amount,
drivernamefuel 
FROM $tablename where carno='$c' 
AND monthdate BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' 
GROUP BY monthdate";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$graphtitle="For The month of $a to $b";//Graph Title
$xname="BarChart Report By Vehicle No : $c";
$yname='VALUE';//y-axis name
$img_width=900;//image height
$img_height=700;//image width 
$margins=70;
$ymargin=6;
$count=mysql_affected_rows();
$graph_width=$img_width - $margins * 2;
$graph_height=$img_height - $margins * 2; 
$bar_width=25;
$total_bars=$count;
$gap= ($graph_width- $total_bars * $bar_width ) / ($total_bars +1);
$img=imagecreate($img_width,$img_height);
include 'barcolor.php';
imagefilledrectangle($img,0,0,0,0,$bag_color);
imageline($img,$margins,$img_height-45,$img_width-20,$img_height-45,$xyline_color);
imageline($img,$margins,$ymargin,$margins,$img_height-45,$xyline_color);
$maxvalue="select max(monthdate) as amount from $tablename";//Give your field name for Y axis 
$max=mysql_query($maxvalue);
while($inf1= mysql_fetch_array($max)) 
  {
   $ratio=$graph_height/$inf1[0];
  }
$horizontal_lines=8;
$horizontal_gap=($img_height+20)/$horizontal_lines;
for($j=1;$j<=$horizontal_lines;$j++)
{
        $y=($img_height-48) - $horizontal_gap * $j ;
        //imageline($img,$margins+1,$y,$img_width-20,$y,$hline_color);
        $v=intval($horizontal_gap * $j /$ratio);
        imagestring($img,2,$margins-30,$y-5,$v,$values_color);
}
$i=0;
while($inf = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {
      $x1=($margins+10) + ($gap+5) + $i * ($gap+$bar_width) ;
      $x2=$x1+$bar_width;
      $y1=($img_height-46)- ceil($inf[1] * $ratio) ; 
      $y2=($img_height-46); 
      imagestring($img,2,$x1+1,$y1-15,$inf[1],$values_color); 
      imagestring($img,2,$x2-23,$img_height-43,$inf[0],$values_color);  
      imagefilledrectangle($img,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$bar_color); // Draw bar
   $i++;   
  }
imagestring($img,8, ($img_width-$margin)/2, 0, $graphtitle, $txt_color);
imagestring($img,5, ($img_width-$margin)/2, $img_height-($ymargin+10), $xname, $txt_color);
imagestringup($img,5,10,($img_height-$ymargin)/2, $yname, $txt_color);
//header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img, 'barchart.jpg');
echo "<div style='border:1px solid #d8d8d8;width:$img_width'><img src='barchart.jpg'></div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing parameters to query, so pass it like below

and also you are not adding
**amount + servicecharges + replacecharges + blockcharges + othercharges** within in the SUM(..) of the selected query, so be sure to replace it

Modify your query as

```
$sql="SELECT CONCAT(monthdate,' ','(',drivernamefuel,')') as drivernamefuel,
   sum(amount +  servicecharges + replacecharges + blockingcharges + othercharges) AS amount,
   drivernamefuel 
   FROM ".$tablename." 
   WHERE carno='".$c."' AND monthdate BETWEEN '".$a."' AND '".$b."' 
   GROUP BY monthdate";
```

Comment: not working it is showing error Warning: Division by zero in Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

Comment: passing parameters like .$c., modified my answer

Comment: remove single coats if it is not needed

Comment: while($inf = mysql_fetch_array($result))  here

Comment: upto query it is ok for you i think :)

Comment: what type of error you are getting here? could you debugg it?

Comment: ok ok can you post your table scripts in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/, so we can easily solve it

Comment: please see my update post i upload screenshort of mysql table

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38764/discussion-between-user2468472-and-naveen)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. Remove qotes ( ' ) and change SUM(fields you want to sum)

```
$sql="SELECT CONCAT(monthdate,' ','(',drivernamefuel,')') as drivernamefuel,sum(amount +  servicecharges + replacecharges + blockcharges + othercharges) AS total_amount,drivernamefuel FROM ".$tablename." where carno='".$c."' AND monthdate BETWEEN '".$a."' AND '".$b."' GROUP BY monthdate"; 

echo $sql;
```

Echo the query in your page and try to execute the query directly in phpMyadmin. Then check what was the issue with your query. Problems may be values you are passing to query

Comment: not working it is showing error Warning: Division by zero in Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

Comment: Could print the sql statement to verify the argument $a, $b, $c is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql="SELECT CONCAT(monthdate,' ','(',drivernamefuel,')') as drivernamefuel, 
SUM(amount +  
servicecharges + 
replacecharges + 
blockcharges + 
othercharges) AS amount,
drivernamefuel 
FROM ".$tablename." where carno='".$c."' 
AND monthdate BETWEEN '".$a."' AND '".$b."' 
GROUP BY monthdate";
```

---

* Note that the mysql extension [is now **deprecated** and will be removed sometime in the future](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). That's because it is ancient, full of bad practices and lacks some modern features. Don't use it to write new code. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead. Your query is prone to [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: not working it is showing error Warning: Division by zero in Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in